pyqt5 повышение прав на запись
Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли как то через pyqt5 повысить права для записи файла через библиотеки python или pyqt, не используя модуль os.
Суть: файл настроек в ОС Debian 12 лежит в /etc/programname/settings.ini, хотелось бы не запускать графическое приложение с правами root, а получить разово права на запись и запись в файл, доступный для записи только для root

Без повышения прав вообще можно. Создай группу programname. Дай файлу настроек эту группу и права на запись для группы. Дай пользователю эту группу. Перезайди в систему и теперь можно записывать в этот файл без повышения прав.

да, как вариант. но хотелось бы в код впихнуть повышение прав

повысить можно только новый процесс, соответсвенно без os или subprocess не обойтись

спасибо за ответ. видимо, придется окольные пути искать. с учетом того, что дебиан 12 отказался от pkexec
